# One large column or many small rows?

Tags: mysql

In a news feed app, our customer requires to store all the ids of articles that read by a user.

We decided to create a single table for this, but from ***performance*** point of view, which of the following is a better approach:

1. Have one row per user with two fields, a `user_id` and `article_ids`, then each time a user read an article, append the id to the article_ids text - using update and concat *(we might end up with a huge data in one column)*.
2. Have many rows with two columns, `user_id` and `article_id`, then each time a user read an article, insert the `article_id` along with the `user_id` in as a new record *(we might end up with too many rows)*.

Or if there is a better way, *any* suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: In general, the second approach is better.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Isn't retrieving a single row is better than retrieving multiple rows? I read that some where IIRC.

Comment: You haven't said how you want to use the data - do you want to be able to identify articles that have not been read or have been read, or how many articles a user has read, or rank users by the number of aritcles read, or articles by the number of users - almost certainly approach 2 is better for all of these.  I can't think of a use case where 1 provides a better model for using the data we have stored ... but there are lots of people more imaginative then me!

Comment: Again, epending on how you want to use the data you may want a table that links the user to the article with a timestamp - allowing you to track multiple access to the same article by the same user.

Comment: I would also go for the second approach, it will make things easier for you if you ever need to fetch or count users who read a specific article, for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many records, one for each `user_id` and `article_id` combination. That's much easier to update (just insert a row, no need to apply logic) and also allows you to get information about articles when you want to list which ones a user has read. You can use a join and retrieve the correct information from the database at once, instead of having to convert a string to ids and then go back to the database to get the additional data.

With proper indexes there's not really such a thing as too many rows.

Answer (score 3):

With the second approach, you can keep track of other things which your client might ask going forward.

- First, open/read/visit time.
- Count of a total number of open/read/visit.
- Last open/read/visit time.

In this approach, you can apply the indexing on `article_id` later on if required.

**Note:** As @Arjan said in his answer, with proper indexing there is no such a thing as too many rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try to split them as much as possible. Your performance will be increased a lot if, because you just have to pick small pieces of your database. If you go for the first option, you have to split it after certain characters to get the information you want. First it is more challenging in programming and if a user has a bad internet connection, the application would be very slow.